# Manipulating junction table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, junction-table

I am creating app with PHP that uses Mysql DB to manage data.
Tables are like this:

```
user         purchasing      medicine
____         ________        ________
id_user      id_user         id_medicine
username     id_medic        item
```

What really bogus me.. should insert values in purchasing(junction table) after i update user, and medicine table?
Should I use transactions for it?

And second question is, are id_user and id_medic in junction table, indexes, or unique?

Sorry, Ive forgot a mysql.
Thanks in advance

Comment: At this point your asking for a solution, but you're not providing the business rules you want to apply i.e. We cannot suggest indexes or unique if we don't know what you require.

Comment: yes, you must first insert values in user and medicine before you insert to purchasing.  otherwise, you won't know id_user or id_medic.  regarding transactions, that depends on several things... transactions are a safety net.  if, for example, you need to guarantee that a user isn't inserted without also having a record in purchasing, then yes, you will want to use transactions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should insert to the `medicine` table first. Because, if you are setting the database properly, the `purchasing.id_medic` should refer to `medicine.id_medicine`, So, inserting into `purchasing` table should fail if there is no such `id_medicine` added before. (And yes, you should use transactions, if you think there is possibility to rollback after inserting some rows).
2. In `purchasing` table, `id_user` and `id_medic` both should be indexes for sure, but whether it should be unique it depends on your use cases. For example :

   - If you think any user can purchase only one item, then `id_user` should be unique.
   - If you think any item cannot be sold more than once, `id_medic` should be unique.
   - If you think any user can buy any item only once, there should be a unique constraint with both `id_user` and `id_medic`